# Слово "рыцарь"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке взялось слово "рыцарь"? Своих рыцарей у нас не было, из немецкого или английского оно тоже не могло прийти (knight - по-английски и кнехт - по-немецки, не знаю, как оно пишется). Откуда же появилось это слово?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Были у нас рыцари. Не точь-в-точь как в Европе, но близкий аналог. Назывались они витязи. 
А само слово рыцарь пришло из польского rусеrz с тем же значеним, которое (по Фасмеру) в свою очередь произошло от средневернхненемецкого ritter.

Comment: А как соотносится с этим названием английское knight?

Comment: Никак.____

Comment: везде это как раз батрак, безземельный крестьянин.
А вообще в морском деле, тумба с набалдашником. Фасмер "забыл" продолжить свою этимологию:
Кнехт "колышек, такелажный крюк, тумба", см. кнек. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973
кнек--"крючок"
А исходное--конек,  цель для набрасывания аркана, петли.
так коней во все времена ловили, рыцарей с коня стаскивали, а на море на такую тумбу петлю при швартовке--бросают.

Comment: Какой еще батрак???

Answer (score 1):

**Ры́царь** (посредством польск. rусеrz, от, нем. Ritter), первоначально — «всадник»